# Probability question involving infinite number of vertical chords in a 1 inch circle.

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics

> Infinite number of vertical chords drawn on a circle with a 1 inch radius. What is the probability that a randomly picked chord is shorter than the radius?

The answer should be

$1 - .5√ 3$ or $.134$

but I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: With problems like this you have to be clear what "random" means (look up Bertrand's Paradox). As you say the chords are vertical, do you mean you choose a uniformly random point on the horizontal diameter and make the chord perpendicular to that?

Comment: The question didn't specify what it meant by "vertical chords" which confused me a bit as well. When I do get a clearer idea of what the question is asking, I'll be sure to update this question.

Comment: well, "vertical chords" will certainly mean chords perpendicular to a fixed diameter (defined to be horizontal).  It's "random" that's the worry.  I believe it means what I said in my first comment.  Assuming that's the case, which points on the horizontal diameter have perpendicular chords equal to a radius?

Comment: As you can see from the answers below, some responders believe "random" means "randomly drawn angle to an endpoint".  That is sensible enough, but it will give a different answer than "randomly chosen intersection with the horizontal diameter".  That illustrates Bertrand's Paradox perfectly.  I am pretty sure you want the second definition but unless it is made explicit the problem is ill-posed.

Comment: As there are a lot of conflicting answers posted here, I'll write out the calculation using my choice of what "random" means and post it below.  I note that my method gives the answer you were given but that does not mean mine was the only sensible choice; it just means that my choice matched whatever reference you are using.

Comment: I am assuming you mean  the lines joining $ (t, \tan t ),(t, -\tan t ) $ for any random $t$. Is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Draw a circle of unit radius. Mark on it a vertical chord of
length $1$ and also a horizontal diameter.  Draw lines between the center of the circle and the ends
of the vertical chord.

What is the distance of the vertical chord that you have drawn
from the center of the circle? What is the length of the diameter
that you have drawn? Now suppose
that the midpoint of the vertical chord "chosen at random"
is uniformly distributed on the horizontal diameter. Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 2):

Put the circle in the standard plane with center at the origin.  I'll assume that "random" means "pick a point randomly on the horizontal diameter and draw the perpendicular chord through that point".  WLOG I will just work with that half of the diameter between x = 0 and x = 1.  We first ask "for which x does the perpendicular chord through x have length 1"?  That is a simple question for Pythagorus and he tells us it is x = $\frac{1}{2}$ $\sqrt{3}$.  Thus the "good" chords will come on the interval between x = $\frac{1}{2}$ $\sqrt{3}$ and x = 1.  It is easy to see that the good interval has length 1 - $\frac{1}{2}$ $\sqrt{3}$.  As the total length was 1, that value is the desired probability.

Just to emphasize:  if you have a different notion of "random" in mind (random angle, random point in the circle interior, random endpoint on the curve, whatever) it is quite likely that the answer will be different.

Comment: Just to say:  it is clear that the endpoint of the vertical chord of length = 1 is at an angle of 30 degrees from the horizontal (the right triangle in question is clearly a 30-60-90 triangle).  thus if "random" meant "random angle" the probability that the chord is shorter than 1 is 1/3 (as 30 degrees is 1/3 of 90).

Answer (score 1):

$\qquad\qquad$ [image]

The total area of the unit circle is $\pi$. Now take a chord the size of the radius. Notice how all other chords parallel to it cut the semi-disc into two regions: the region with chord-length smaller than the radius, and the one with chord-length greater than the radius, but smaller than the diameter. Can you compute the area of each, knowing that the regular hexagon inscribed in the circle has side-length equal to the radius of the circle ?

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

Draw your circle in a Cartesian plane, with center in the origin.

Fix a point on the circle, let's say $(x_0, y_0)$. Then pick another point $(x_1, y_1)$. This is a way to randomly pick a chord in your circle. In particular, the chord joins $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$.

Without loss of generalities, let's say that $(x_0, y_0) = (1, 0)$ and consider that $(x_1, y_1) = (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$, for some $\theta$.
In this case, we can say that $\theta$ is randomly drawn in the set $[0, 2\pi)$ with equal probability.

The length of the chord is:

$$L = \sqrt{(\cos(\theta) - 1)^2 + \sin^2(\theta)} = \sqrt{\cos^2(\theta) +1 - 2\cos(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)} = \\
= \sqrt{2(1 - \cos(\theta))}.$$

Now, we want to compute the probability that $L < 1$. Namely:

$$P(L < 1) = P\left(\sqrt{2(1 - \cos(\theta))}<1\right) = P\left(2(1 - \cos(\theta))<1\right) = \\
= P\left(\cos(\theta)>\frac{1}{2}\right) = P\left(\theta\in\left[0, \frac{\pi}{3}\right] \vee \theta\in\left[\frac{5\pi}{3}, 2\pi\right) \right) = \\
= P\left(\theta\in\left[0, \frac{\pi}{3}\right] \right) + P\left(\theta\in\left[\frac{5\pi}{3}, 2\pi\right) \right).$$

The probability density function of $\theta$ is uniform on $[0, 2\pi)$, and hence:

$$P(L < 1) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{1}{2\pi} \text{d}\theta + \int_{\frac{5\pi}{3}}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi} \text{d}\theta = \frac{1}{3}.$$

The probability you are looking for is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @lulu it seems that $1-0.5 \sqrt{3}$ is the right answer. Why may way doesn't work? Where is my mistake?

Comment: No mistake, the problem was imprecise.  You are using a different probability measure on the space of vertical paths.  Specifically, you are using arclength  (a.k.a. angle) where one might use the linear measure inherited from the diameter.  In my solution, below, I show how to pass from the linear measure to the one derived from angle...getting 1/3, as you did, from the angle.